# Confusing cb results with ips cb_type

Tags: vowpalwabbit

Is cb_type ips expected to be much better than dm or dr?

I wrote the script here (results included) https://gist.github.com/travisbrady/546b40a0ed328d8f83dbc6230ee83fec using the personalization bandit data from Tony Jebara's ML for personalization class and the evaluation metric ("take rate") varies by a lot as I change the cb_type.
Specifically 0.23 for dm, 0.79 for dr and 0.85 for ips. Those jumps are quite large so I'm wondering if I've misunderstood something.

Is this expected? Is ips typically the better choice? In what circumstances is each cb_type preferred?

Answer (score 0):

From your gist, the action probabilities are all declared as 1/10, so an effective difference between dm and ips is a factor of 10 in the learning rate.

Secondarily, `--mtr` is the typically best option but this is only available in the `--cb_adf` code path.